# How to test a Asterisk Sign

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I need to test the asterisk sign (required Field) using appium for Android .
.getText is not working. what other method should i use to grab the asterisk sign so that i can validate it is a required field. please see the image below.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You need to test it for what?

Comment: Maybe you are doing `.getText()` on the wrong element?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to call `driver.getPageSource()` and inspect the source XML. The XML format is different in UIAutomator and UIAutomator2, so if you are testing on Android 5 you should try both `automationName` capabilities.

If you will be able to find element with `*` text or just element most likely representing asterisk next to password `android.widget.EditText` input, then you can search for it and validate if its present.

However, if asterisk symbol is part of password `android.widget.EditText` input element (most likely), then you probably won't get it: in my case I don't get dots that hides password as well - empty text in Appium Desktop inspector.

If its critical, you need to ask developers to put it in separate element, but I doubt it makes any sense to focus on it so much